# Windows 8.1 store app Facebook Integration error

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8.1

I'm getting following error while integrating facebook api over Windows 8.1 for store apps:-

> **Given URL is not permitted by application configuration......"**

Screenshot showing error dialog:

[image: Error screenshot]

Please help to resolve this issue.

```
private FacebookSession _session;
private FacebookClient _client;
private string _accessToken;
string appID = "749110128499368";


Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>{
    {"response_type","token"},
    {"display","touch"},
    {"redirect_uri","https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"},
    };
FacebookClient oauth;
string[] extended_permissions;

async void getToken()
{
    try
    {
        FacebookSessionClient fbClient = new FacebookSessionClient(appID);
        if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey("fbaccesstoken"))
        {
            _accessToken = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["fbaccesstoken"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            _session = await fbClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream");
            _accessToken = _session.AccessToken;
            ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["fbaccesstoken"] = _accessToken;
        }

        _client = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);                
    }
    catch (Exception e){

        extended_permissions = new string[] { "user_friends", "email" };
        oauth = new FacebookClient() { AppId = appID };
        if (extended_permissions != null && extended_permissions.Length > 0)
        {
            var scope = new StringBuilder();
            scope.Append(string.Join(",", extended_permissions));
            parameters["scope"] = scope.ToString();
        }
        getLogin();
    }
}

void getLogin()
{
    oauth.Version = "2.2";
    extended_permissions = new string[] { "user_friends", "email" };
    oauth = new FacebookClient() { AppId = appID };
    if (extended_permissions != null && extended_permissions.Length > 0)
    {
        var scope = new StringBuilder();
        scope.Append(string.Join(",", extended_permissions));
        parameters["scope"] = scope.ToString();
    }
    var loginUrl = oauth.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
    fbBrowser.Navigate(loginUrl);
}

async private void fb_browser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    FacebookOAuthResult fb_result;
    var fb = new FacebookClient();
    string uri = e.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
    Uri uri_fb = new Uri(uri);
    if (fb.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(uri_fb, out fb_result))
    {
        if (fb_result.IsSuccess)
        {
            _accessToken = fb_result.AccessToken;
            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,()=>
            {
                GetData(_accessToken);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var errordescription = fb_result.ErrorDescription;
            var errorreason = fb_result.ErrorReason;
            MessageDialog m = new MessageDialog(errordescription + "\n" + errorreason);
            await m.ShowAsync();

        }
    }
}

async void GetData(string access_token)
{
    string uriString = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + access_token;

    HttpClient wClient = new HttpClient();

    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,()=>
    {
        Task gettingData = wClient.GetStringAsync(uriString);


    });
}
```

Comment: You should include (if possible) all relevant information in your question. You don't even show the code that is causing this problem.

Comment: @t3chb0t  Have you seen my edit?

Comment: Yes, I have. This was rather a general info to include all relevant information so that other people who can help can do it at all. I'm afraid I am not able to help you with that but I think you should check the application permissions as the error message says.

Comment: @t3chb0t i finally solved this. This was due to incorrect app settings. I just enabled option "Embedded browser OAuth Login" inside security section of Advanced Setting Tab and it works. Thanks for your support

Comment: It's good to hear that you finally managed to find the solution. Reading error messages twice might be a good idea because most of the times they are helpful and give a hint on what might be wrong ;-)